# How to open secured url in html using src attribute

Tags: c#, html, jquery, azure-web-app-service, kudu

I have an API hosted on Azure which compare two pdf files and generate a new resultant pdf. I want to open resultant pdf in my html web page using embed tag. when i put kudu file url in src attribute of embed tag it is not able to open because of security reason.
When i use src="username:password@testpdfcomparison.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/site/wwwroot/pdf/Output.pdf" then i got this error in browser:

Subresource requests whose URLs contain embedded credentials (e.g. `https://user:pass@host/`) are blocked. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5669008342777856 for more details.

Actually i want to open this pdf file with silent login. Can i do this by any other way through jquery or c#

This is the pdf file link:
https://testpdfcomparison.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/site/wwwroot/pdf/Output.pdf

Comment: Server side proxy endpoint to get the pdf contents might work. Use that endpoint as the `src` and have it send the credentials while getting the file

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/microsoft-logins?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: @charlietfl can you show me an example how to do it

Comment: Not really, have little to no background in C#. Getting a file from another server though is a common task and once you get it you would then just output it

Comment: @jdweng i just want to display that pdf on html embed or iframe tag by providing the credential

Comment: @charlietfl you mean i should have to download it from the server to my local machine and then display it right?

Comment: No not at all, the src points to an endpoint (url) on your server, when request comes in it retrieves the pdf file from other server and outputs it to original request to display in browser. Or could be on same server

Comment: You cannot do something that the server doesn't support.  You cannot use the authentication method you are currently using.

Comment: Has your problem been solved and is there any progress?

Comment: thank you all for your response now i resolved it by returning filename and use relative path instead of `src="username:password@testpdfcomparison.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/site/wwwroot/pdf/Output.pdf"`
 
by using jquery:

`if (Data) {
                        var embed1 = document.getElementById('outputPdf');
                        embed1.src = "../../pdf/" + Data;
                        $("#outputPdf").css("display", "block");
                    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why your `.pdf` file path includes `scm`.

**No matter what language code your program uses, the generated pdf file, stored in a certain folder under the current operating environment, must use a relative path.** (It is recommended to use azure storage if there are a lot of files)

The file path in azure webapp contains `scm`, so authorization verification must be performed. For example, the document link you provided, my account does not have permission to access it. As shown below.

[image]

In fact, azure app services is essentially an `iis`. When we write code, files need to be stored. It is recommended to use `relative paths`. The file path is as follows, my sample code is `.net core 3.0`.

[image]

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "Html")),
            RequestPath = "/Html"
        });
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "PDF")),
            RequestPath = "/PDF"
        });
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "api")),
            RequestPath = "/api"
        });
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

You can [download my sample code](https://github.com/Jason446620/GeneralWeb/tree/master/deploy_cert_include_core), and deploy it. And you can access below two urls.

1. `https://yourwebsitename.azurewebsites.net/Html/a.html` .
2. `https://yourwebsitename.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/site/wwwroot/pdf/testpdf.pdf` .

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time.I have not tested it but think it should work